# JavaScript Sort Complex JSON by latest deepest value

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I've a this type of JSON, with variable keys (converted from the map)

```
'NON_OPERATIONAL': {
                'BROADCAST': { 
                  'Availibility': { 
                      '102': 10, 
                      '109': 6, 
                      '105':3 
                  }, 
                  'Polling': { 
                      '243': 23, 
                      '235':8, 
                      '230':5 
                  },
                  'Pop': { 
                      '300': 55, 
                      '301':3, 
                      '302':9 
                  } 
                },
                'DISPLAY': { 
                  'Temperature': { 
                      '100': 12, 
                      '101': 7, 
                      '102':3 
                  }, 
                  'Fan': { 
                      '220': 50, 
                      '221':2, 
                      '222':1 
                  },
                  'Rendering': { 
                      '305': 40, 
                      '306':30, 
                      '307':10
                  } 
                }
              }
```

the desired result is to obtain the (x) top values, if i suppose to get just 4 elements, the result will be like this :

```
1- ('BROADCAST' -> 'POP' ->  '300' -> 55);
2- ('DISPLAY' -> 'Fan' ->  '220' -> 50);
3- ('BROADCAST' -> 'Rendering' ->  '305' -> 40);
4- ('BROADCAST' -> 'Rendering' ->  '306' -> 30);
```

Is it possible ?
Thank's for your help

Comment: in what data structure do you want the result? what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

By getting an array with all values with their keys, you could collect them first, sort and slice to get top values with their pathes.

```js
const
    getNested = object => Object
        .entries(object)
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? getNested(v).map(a => [k, ...a])
            : [[k, v]]
        ),
    last = array => array[array.length - 1],
    data = { BROADCAST: { Availibility: { 102: 10, 109: 6, 105: 3 }, Polling: { 243: 23, 235: 8, 230: 5 }, Pop: { 300: 55, 301: 3, 302: 9 } }, DISPLAY: { Temperature: { 100: 12, 101: 7, 102: 3 }, Fan: { 220: 50, 221: 2, 222: 1 }, Rendering: { 305: 40, 306: 30, 307: 10 } } },
    result = getNested(data)
        .sort((a, b) => last(b) - last(a))
        .slice(0, 4);

result.forEach(a => console.log(a.join(' -> ')));
```

Comment: I've this error in flatMap: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type '[string, unknown][]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2019' or later

Comment: i have no idea of typescript. [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is standard javascript.

Comment: I've resolved it by adding es2019 to tsconfig, i'll try